# Sklearn - svm weighted features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

Hi I am quite new in machine learning with scikit-learn but I have a question.

Is it possible to make svm recognize some features of my vector data with higher importance or weight. I do not know the correct therm :/

Here is example of what I want:

Let's say we have bunch of vecotrs in 2d array:

```
dt = [
[x1, y1, z1, q1],
[x2, y2, z2, q2],
[x3, y3, z3, q3],
[x4, y4, z4, q4]]
```

And target data vector:

```
target = [1,0,0,1]
```

What I want to know how can I make, for example, all q features for each of vectors in dt more important than rest of the features.

I know how to balance data by sets or to set sample_weight but neither can help me with this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if you use sklearn.svm.SVC for classification you can access coef_ atribute of the classifier object. For example:

```
classifier = SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', random_state=241)
classifier.fit(dt, target)
coef = classifier.coef_ # here the weights of the features will be stored
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html - documentation for more details.

Comment: Ok I understand now how to access data that represents weight features but is there a way I can change them. Documentation clearly states this coef_ is a readonly property. I want to make my classifier take some of the features more importantly by force.

Comment: I can express an assumption only, without use of library.
SVM - it's linear method and it's sensitive to features scales.
You can use StandartScaler (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) to fit them to one scale (not necessary, but sometimes it can dramatically increase the efficiency of your algorithm).
Then you can preprocess your training data yourself and scale all features you see not important with coef < 1 (don't forget to save it for applying this scaling to the test set or\and real data).

You need more experiments:)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this approach